# Is there a way for a preview for comments?

Tags: feature-request

When I write a comment, I often permute the backticks. So I have to edit it.
When it is not much work to implement such a feature, it would be nice :D.

Comment: Currently, no, there is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround is to go to the [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/195817),
a pseudo-question on the super-meta site
that exists specifically to allow people to experiment with formatting. 
You still may need to do repeated edits to get it right,
but at least people won’t be watching you while you do it.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. The Formating Sandbox is nice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can edit your comment in the `answer box`, after you finish editing, you can copy/paste to the `comment box`. They share the some common rules for editing.

Comment: except that in an answer box, you can hit the enter key. In a comment box, if you try that, you submit your comment ;-)

Comment: In the following comment, I use “tick” and “slash” as shorthand for “backtick” and “backslash”, because it’s very close to the 600 character limit as it is.

Comment: The bigger problem is that formatting works differently in posts (Qs and As) versus comments — particularly when you want to format special characters `as code`. In a post, you need to use `\`\` \` \`\`` (tick tick space tick space tick tick) to get a tick in code format (`\``), but that doesn’t work in comments, where you must use `\`\⁠\`\`` (tick slash tick tick). Backslashes are almost as bad; `\`\⁠\`` (tick slash tick) in a post will get you a code-formatted backslash (``\``), but this doesn’t work in comments.  Luckily, `\`\`\⁠\`\`` (tick tick slash tick tick) works in either place.

Comment: Also, HTML-isms like `<code>` and `&#96;` will work in posts but not comments.

Comment: And, yes, getting the above comment formatted correctly was very difficult. Warning: Gödel’s Incompleteness Theorem applies — the above comment does not contain (explain) all the information that you need to know to ***create*** the above comment.  Warning #2: if you copy and paste the above comment, you may get some characters that you weren’t expecting (non-displaying characters).  These may give you clues as to how I created the above comment.